# Help checking the correct meaning of '遐想连篇'

Tags: translation, idioms

I'm not sure whether the phrase has a typo in it or not because I couldn't find the proper translation from MDBG, Ichacha or Ichiba. However, I did find an example:

> 中国的5000年悠久历史、丰富多样的风俗文化以及无处不在的神秘感，让许多外国人心驰神往，遐想连篇。

China’s 5000 year history, the variety of its customs and cultures, and its general mystique, have always pulled on the hearts and imagination of westerners.

I take '遐想连篇' here means making you imagining or drawing your imagination out.

I'm not sure I got the correct meaning though. I think sometimes it doesn't make any sense. For example: 
'Pulling (your) imagination' make sense in 让人遐想连篇的小说, but not in 让人遐想连篇的话语

Do you have a better way to put the phrase '遐想连篇' in english?

Comment: 遐想连篇 is commonly used especially in written. another similar one is "浮想联翩"， which is the same in meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

遐想 means '**reverie**; **fantasy**; **day dream**'

篇 is a classifier for 'article', as in 一篇文章 (an article)

连篇 means 'one (article) after another'

Since fantasy is an imagined story in one's head, 篇 is a correct classifier.

"遐想连篇" in English is "one fantasy after another" or " one day dream after another" (day dream is fantasy)

Other examples of 连篇 as "one after another" with 篇 as a classifier:

- 谎话连篇 - one lie after another (a lie is a made-up story)
- 废话连篇 - one bullshit after another (bullshit is the same as nonsensical article--  both are telling nonsensical story)

> '遐' means "far away"; '**遐想**' literally means " **far away thought**" (a thought that is far away from reality)

Comment: And thereI was, wondering what 连篇 means.... It makes sense now, thanks

Answer (score 1):

中国的5000年悠久历史、
The Middle Kingdom's 5000 year long history,
丰富多样的风俗文化
rich and diverse customs and culture
以及无处不在的神秘感，
as well as its all-pervasive feeling of mystery,
让许多外国人心驰神往，
fascinates and infatuates many a foreigner,
遐想连篇。
causing endless flights of fancy and imagination.